# javascript variable content in quotes

Tags: javascript, php

this is regarding passing arguments to a function in javascript.
This code is not working. Is it because of the _(underscore) in the $l?? if yes, what change should be brought in the code. Thanks in advance. Please not the $l value will be passed to another page using ajax and queried into a database.

```
    <script>
    function show(str)
    {
     var r=str;
     alert(r);
    }
    </script>


   <?php
   $l=Somethin_nothin_anythin;
   echo "<select onChange='show($l)'>";
   echo "<option></option>";
   echo "</select>";
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be:

```
$l="something_nothing_anything":
 echo "<select onChange='show(\'".$l."\')'>";
 echo "<option></option>"; 
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: you are passing php string in javascript without quotes

Comment: when i inspected dat element ,its showing show(something_nothing_anything)... but somehow the function in javascript show is  not accepting this value passed to it.the console output is showing a reference error something_anything_nothing is not defined

Comment: Its not possible.. U r doing some mistake.. Copy and paste the above code as it is and check